# Building Linux Kernel from source. Nothing appears in ~/rpmbuild/BUILD

Tags: linux-kernel, centos

I'm following the directions [here](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source). In the last step it says

> The kernel source tree will now be found under the ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/ directory. "

However, when I go into this directory, I see nothing. Any ideas? I've done everything else the page says.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running an old version of rpmbuild, which used `/usr/src/packages/` instead of `~/rpmbuild`.